# Boolean parenthesisation in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

The boolean parenthesisation problem is to count the number of ways to parenthesise a given binary expression so that it evaluates to true.

I wrote a C++ solution according to the explanation given [here](http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~bcdean/dp_practice/dp_9.swf) ([small video explanation here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-37-boolean-parenthesization-problem/)), but it always returns zero. My code seems very similar to the code given on the first page (I didn't look at before writing mine), but it works where mine doesn't. What mistake am I making?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> vals(n);
    vector<int> ops(n - 1); //ops[n] is the operator
                             //between the nth and (n-1)th values
    char tmp;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; ++i) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            cin >> vals[i / 2];
        } else {
            cin >> ops[i / 2];
        }
    }

    vector<vector<int> > t(n, vector<int>(n, 0)),
                         f(n, vector<int>(n, 0));

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        t[i][i] = vals[i] == 1;
        f[i][i] = vals[i] == 0;
    }

    const int AND = 6, OR = 1, XOR = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 2; ++i) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n - 1; ++j) {
            for(int k = i; k < j; ++k) {
                cout << endl << i << " " << j << " " << k << endl;
                switch(ops[k]) {
                    case AND:
                        t[i][j] = t[i][k] * t[k + 1][j];  //T & T = T
                        f[i][j] = f[i][k] * f[k + 1][j]   //F & F = F
                                + f[i][k] * t[k + 1][j]   //F & T = F
                                + t[i][k] * f[k + 1][j];  //T & F = F

                    case OR:
                        t[i][j] = t[i][k] * t[k + 1][j]   //etc
                                + f[i][k] * t[k + 1][j]
                                + t[i][k] * f[k + 1][j];
                        f[i][j] = f[i][k] * f[k + 1][j];

                    case XOR:
                        t[i][j] = f[i][k] * t[k + 1][j]
                                + t[i][k] * f[k + 1][j];
                        f[i][j] = f[i][k] * f[k + 1][j]
                                + t[i][k] * t[k + 1][j];
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                        cout << t[i][j] << " ";
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }
            } //k loop
        } //j loop
    } //i loop

    cout << endl << t[0][n - 1];
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Yes, but I'm not exactly getting any errors . . . what can I do with `gdb` in this case?

Comment: What you can do with a debugger : inspect the state of your process, query the variables and the call frame & run it step by step; think about your program; understand what is wrong; improve your program; recompile; and repeat until you are happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

The outer two loops (`i` and `j`) are not the right ones. What you're doing in your code is start from one end of the expression, moving towards the other end (the `i` loop), and try to calculate increasingly wide subexpressions that begin at the current position (width `j - i`, the `j` loop). The problem is that, in order to calculate parenthesizing variations for an expression of width `k`, you need all the values for its subexpressions of width `k - 1` and smaller, which, in your solution, you haven't calculated yet (not all of them, anyway). So, you're relying on values that are not calculated yet and default to `0`, which gives you nice fat zeroes in those multiplications.

As with any dynamic programming problem, the trick is to build all values for width `k` *only after* you've calculated all relevant values for width `k - 1`. So, the outer two loops should look something like this:

```
//You've calculated width 0 in the loop before, so start at 1.
for(int width = 1; width < n; ++width)
   for(int i = 0, j = i + width; j < n; ++i, ++j)
      //The inner loop looks OK at first glance, 
      //but I haven't looked at it in depth.
```

Keep in mind this is *untested, unimplemented code*, it's only based on my understanding of the dynamic programming problem in this case (my understanding has been known to be wrong from time to time...). However, it should give you a head start in clearing things up.